# attribute error that i cant understand the reason for

Tags: mysql, pyqt5, attributeerror, pymysql, mysql-connector-python

this is my code. i am new to this. someone plz help solve this error.

```
def database(self):
    don = mdb.connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'project')
    with don:
        cur = don.cursor()

        cur.execute("INSERT INTO p1(name, age)"
                    "VALUES('%s', '%s')" % (''.join(self.lineEdit_2.text()),
                                            ''.join(self.lineEdit_3.text())))

        QMessageBox.about(self, 'Connection', 'Data Inserted Successfully')
        self.close()
```

error:
with don:
AttributeError: **enter**

Comment: which mysql python modules are you using in ur code?

Comment: i'm  using pymysql,mysqlclient

Answer (score 0):

```
def database(self):
  don = mdb.connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'project')

  with don.cursor() as cur:
      cur.execute("INSERT INTO p1(name, age)"
                "VALUES('%s', '%s')" % (''.join(self.lineEdit_2.text()),
                                        ''.join(self.lineEdit_3.text())))

      QMessageBox.about(self, 'Connection', 'Data Inserted Successfully')
       self.close()
```

Comment: thank you for your help.now it says data is inserted and there is no attribute error but when i look in phpmyadmin it shows no entries.

Comment: cur.execute("INSERT INTO p1 (name, age) VALUES('stack',20)")                                            don.commit()                                                                                                                             try this @mmm if this works u need to check your join statement

Comment: this is producing the same:   with con:
AttributeError: __enter__